# Reinstall postgres cluser in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I seem to have somehow deleted my postgres binaries (ubuntu 22.04).
Running `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib` reinstalled the binaries for the pg 14 cluster:

```
18:42 $ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
13  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
14  main    5432 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

Running `sudo pg_createcluster --start 12 main` gives `Error: no initdb program for version 12 found`

How do I reinstall postgres versions 12 and 13? I have existing databases in these clusters.

Also:

```
apt-cache showpkg postgresql
```

gives:

```
Package: postgresql
Versions: 
14+238 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ie.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/apt/lists/ie.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_main_binary-i386_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

Comment: What repo are you using the Ubuntu one or [PGDG](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) one?

Comment: I seem to be using the Ubuntu repo http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Do you recommend one over the other @Adrian Klaver?

Comment: The Ubuntu repo only supplies one version of Postgres for a given version of Ubuntu. For Ubuntu 22.04 that is Postgres 14. If you want to install more then one version you need the PGDG repo. Given that you has multiple versions before I'm going to say you where using the PGDG repo before.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually run into something similar recently, having to install Postgresql-9.1 into a ubuntu 22.04. The default apt repo only has the 14 version, you can check this by runing the command:

`apt list | grep ^postgresql`

That being said, you must then configure an apt source that has the corresponding postgresql image(s) that you want. You can do so by following the instructions in the following link: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt. This is a link to configure your apt to use the postgres apt repo, which has most if not all postgresql images.

After that you only need to list again:

`apt list | grep ^postgresql`

**I recommend backing up your db files before, in case the installation overwrites anything**

and download your image with  :

`apt install`

I can't guarantee the binaries will have the same location or naming, so maybe you will need to do some configuration for the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions to use the pgdg repo, as advised by @Adrian Klaver, from here worked: [postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

Then running `sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12`